# Using nodejs how can I return an object containing all the data from a batch of API calls in a loop?

Tags: node.js, callback

I'm aware of closures and callbacks in JavaScript but it's obvious I don't get them on an intuitive level.

I have a small app that is scraping data from an API and I can easily `console.log` the responses from each request, my problem is I'm trying to gather the data and build an object to save to a file when all requests are complete.

I get that nodejs is a single thread of execution and it doesn't block but I can't figure out where to put the call backs when all the inner requests are finished I can `console.log` the built object. You'll see my `console.log` lines are in the wrong place and execute before the first response from the inner request.

**Breakdown**

1. Fetch country data
2. Loop over countryResponse and use each country id to fetch details
3. Add each detail to an array
4. Add array to object when all requests are complete.

**code**

```
const limit = require("simple-rate-limiter");

let request = limit(require("request")).to(1).per(200);


let options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://myendpoint/details',
    headers: {
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: {
        "token": "TOKEN",
        "method": "countries"
    },
    json: true
};

global.package = {};
global.services = {};
let countryServices = [];

/*
    Country fetch
*/
request(options, function (err, response, countryResponse) {
    if (err) {}

    package.countries = countryResponse;

    countryResponse.forEach(function (entry) {

        let innerOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'https://myendpoint/details',
            headers: {
                'cache-control': 'no-cache',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: {
                "token": "TOKEN",
                "method": "services"
            },
            json: true
        };
        //THIS LINE OMG
        //let countryServices = [];

        innerOptions.body.countryCode = entry.countryCode;

        request(innerOptions, function (err, response, innerResponse) {
            if (err) {}

            countryServices.push(innerResponse);
            console.log(" inner response " + entry.countryCode + ' : ' + JSON.stringify(innerResponse, null, ""));

        });//END innerResponse
    });//END countryResponse.forEach
    services = countryServices;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(package, null, ""));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(countryServices, null, ""));
});//END orderResponse
```

**countryResponse**

```
[
    {
        "countryCode": 1,
        "countryName": "Virgin Islands (U.S.)"
    },
    {
        "countryCode": 7,
        "countryName": "Russian Federation"
    }
]
```

**innerResponse**

```
[
    {
        "Type": "1",
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "Type": "2",
        "id": 3
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most concise and straightforward way to do this may be `async/await` way. You can manually promisify `request` and replace `simple-rate-limiter` dependency with simple delay:

```js
'use strict';

const request = require('request');

function promisifiedRequest(options) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(options, (err, response, body) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve(body);
    });
  });
}

function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => { setTimeout(resolve, ms); });
}

const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://myendpoint/details',
  headers: {
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: {
    token: 'TOKEN',
    method: 'countries',
  },
  json: true,
};

(async function main() {
  try {
    const countryResponse = await promisifiedRequest(options);

    const innerRequests = [];
    for (const entry of countryResponse) {
      const innerOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://myendpoint/details',
        headers: {
          'cache-control': 'no-cache',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: {
          token: 'TOKEN',
          method: 'services',
          countryCode: entry.countryCode,
        },
        json: true,
      };

      const innerRequest = promisifiedRequest(innerOptions);
      innerRequests.push(innerRequest);
      await delay(200);
    }

    const countryServices = await Promise.all(innerRequests);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(countryServices, null, ''));
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

These materials can be helpful if you want more background or need to scale your app (add parallel requests with more complicated rate limits):

[Stackoverflow: How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

[Stackoverflow: Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

[Handling asynchronous operations in parallel](https://itnext.io/node-js-handling-asynchronous-operations-in-parallel-69679dfae3fc)

[Back-off and retry using JavaScript arrays and promises](https://philbooth.me/blog/back-off-and-retry-using-javascript-arrays-and-promises)

Comment: Thank you for that, I definitely have a lot to absorb there and I see a lot of reading ahead. One thing I noticed, in my naive approach it completes it's run ~19 seconds but your solution is ~85 seconds. Is this because yours is async and it will only make a request after the previous request is complete + 200ms delay; where as mine will fire of a request once ever 200ms?

Comment: Yes. I can try to edit to achieve the same behavior. I will add a comment a bit later.

Comment: Can you try the new variant with some tiny changes?

Comment: Yeah, down to ~20s! :) It took me a minute to see that you constructed an array of `promisifiedRequest`s and then called `Promise.all` on that. Thank you so much, I have a lot to mull over and will be adding more nested calls depending on responses.

Comment: @chrisloughnane Happy coding)

Answer (score 1):

The `console.log`s at the end of your code won't wait for all the asynchronous operations fired off by your `forEach` to complete before they run. You'll need to introduce some kind of mechanism that waits for all the functions fired by forEach to complete their requests.

If you want to stick with using callbacks, then you could take a look at using something like the `each` method of [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async), which will handle this kind of situation for you.

This problem is commonly handled using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). If you used a [promise based interface to request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise), your example would look something like this, assuming a fairly up to date version of Node.js (options omitted):

```js
const request = require('request-promise');

async function run() {
  const options = {};
  const countryServices = [];
  const countryResponse = await request(options);

  for (const country of countryResponse) {
    const innerOptions = {};
    const innerResponse = await request(innerOptions);
    countryServices.push(innerResponse);
  }

  console.log(countryServices);
}

run();
```

This is a bit clearer than using callbacks, and the for-of loop behaves exactly how you would expect.